# Swapping Various Textures in Resource Packs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been wanting to use the textures for wool and redstone items from the [CodeCrafted](http://codecrafted.net/) resource pack in the [Faithful 32](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/resource-packs/1223254-faithful-32x32-pack-update-red-cat-clay-1-8) resource pack, so what I was wondering is how I can put the textures that I wan tfrom CodeCrafted into Faithful 32.

Any help would be appreciated also I have looked all over the other Resource Pack related questions and none of them seemed to be relevant to this or did not help what so ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when in minecraft, go to your options and then to your recourcepacks, there you should find the two mentioned recourcepacks.

click the two recourcepacks to the right side and make sure that the CodeCrafted RP is above the Faithful RP, this will override the mentioned textures in minecraft and should end up as a combination of the two

Otherwise you can always move the desired textures from one RP to the other using WinRAR